# How To Load ( Installed) Components In Vue Composition API

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I'm trying to load `vue3-burger-menu` but the documentation only works for `Options API`. I on the other hand use `Composition API` and I'm kinda stuck.

This is what the documentation says:

```
import { Slide } from 'vue3-burger-menu'  // import the CSS transitions you wish to use, in this case we are using `Slide`

export default {
    components: {
        Slide // Register your component
    }
}
```

But `export default` doesn't work for me.

So, how can I load `Slide`?

Comment: You just need to import it, so the first line of the example, vue will do the rest.

Comment: @Lk77 I tried that but it doesn't work

Comment: What does not work ? what error do you have ? You should be able to use it in you template like so `<Slide>`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [working playground](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-wwkpny?file=src/App.vue) with [vue3-burger-menu](https://github.com/mkdillard/vue3-burger-menu) sample.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-wwkpny?file=src/App.vue

You have to put the code from your question in a custom component.

Like this:

**MyMenu.vue**

```
<template>
    <Slide>
      <a id="home" href="#">
        <span>Home</span>
      </a>
    </Slide>
</template>

<script>
import { Slide } from 'vue3-burger-menu'  // import the CSS transitions you wish to use, in this case we are using `Slide`

export default {
    components: {
        Slide // Register your component
    }
}
</script>
```

And use it in the app:

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <MyMenu />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import MyMenu from './components/MyMenu.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    MyMenu
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thats options api, so its not what the op wants

Comment: No, it is not `Options Api` here. It's just a component without `<script setup>`.  Check the Docs: https://vuejs.org/guide/components/registration.html#local-registration

Comment: It's not the recommended way, to me it looks like options api. OP did not paste code so we don't know but i'm pretty sure he is using script setup if he followed the doc.